# Добавление полной ссылки в базу mysql

Tags: mysql

Как добавить полную ссылку на профиль из соц. сети типа `http://ok.ru/profile/584976889622` или `http://facebook.com/profilename`?

если делать без экранирования и прочего как простой текст то пишет такую ошибку

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''testimonial'('name', 'link_soc', 'testimonial') VALUES ('Alexandr', 'http://ok.' at line 1**

сам запрос 
`$addTestimonials = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'testimonial'('name', 'link_soc', 'testimonial') VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$message."')");`
где

```
$email = "Alexandr";
$name = "http://ok.ru/profile/584976889622";
$message = "OK";
```

Comment: Имена таблиц и полей, должны быть в обратных кавычках (буква "Ё" / тильда ~), а не в одинарных или двойных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед добавлением

```
 $name = "http://ok.ru/profile/584976889622";
 $name_ = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Затем при выводе

```
 htmlspecialchars_decode($name_);
```

Comment: Зачем эти лишние действия? У автора ошибка из-за неправильных кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

здесь ошибка в синтаксисе, никак не связанная со ссылками:

```
$addTestimonials = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'testimonial'('name', 'link_soc',
'testimonial') VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$message."')");
```

вокруг имён идентификаторов не должно быть кавычек <kbd>'</kbd>:

```
$addTestimonials = mysql_query("INSERT INTO testimonial(name, link_soc,
testimonial) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$message."')");
```

но если по какой-то причине вам требуется выделить эти идентификаторы, то надо использовать символ <kbd>`</kbd>:

```
$addTestimonials = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `testimonial`(`name`, `link_soc`,
`testimonial`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$message."')");`
```